# How to keep webserver responsive while executing many asynchronous background tasks

Tags: spring, multithreading, tomcat, asynchronous, aop

I am working on a web application that provides its users to optionally execute long-running processes '***in background***'. An example would be some long-running report generation, or deleting thousands of objects simultaneously.

I've implemented this using an ExecutorService defined as FixedThreadPool using a ThreadFactory. The ThreadFactory is built like this:

```
ThreadFactoryBuilder()
            .setNameFormat(clientId + "-BackgroundTask-%d")
            .setDaemon(true)
            .setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY)
            .build()
```

I execute the task like this:

```
Future<TaskStatus> future = clientExecutors.get(clientId).submit(
            backgroundTask::execute);
    taskFutures.put(backgroundTask.getTaskId(), future);
```

How can I enforce my webserver to **always priorize handling new incoming requests** (as fast as possible) over executing background tasks?

In other words: It should never ever happen, that a user has to wait long time while browsing the site, just because there are a lot of background-tasks executing. As you can see from above, I tried to do this by setting `.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY)`. However that does not seem to be sufficient.

Furthermore, as for now, I've set some arbitrary value for the FixedThreadPool size (10) and use it globally for the entire background-handling of the application (and all its customers).

Instead I would like to define a threadpool for each customer, to make sure each customer has the same privilege to run a certain amount of tasks in the background. Say, each customer has a FixedThreadPool of size 5, and on the server I'll have a max. of 50 different customers. That would add up to 250 running background tasks at the same time.

The most important requirement here is: it does not matter, how long these background-tasks need to execute (say 2 minutes, or 20 minutes). What is important, is that each customer has the ability to send 5 tasks to be executed in background, and each of those are worked on **equally**.

I've tested running 30 cpu-intensive background tasks and it turns out that while these are running and cpu is near 100%, new incoming requests take a very long time to be handled.

So obviously, I am doing it wrong.

**Update 12.09.2017**
I've read about microservices and while it sounds great I see a great challenge in splitting the necessary parts from our monolithic application. Mostly because nearly every operation might turn into a long running process given a big enough data selection. 
Furthermore, wouldn't I run into the same problem with my microservice, i.e. the server running the microservice would suffer the same performance degradation. Well the only good thing would, that the rest of the web app would not suffer from it anymore.

I've read some posts about introducing Thread.sleep(1) or Thread.sleep in general into CPU-heavy operations to reduce the amount of CPU used in these operations. I've also read about someone who introduced this as an aspect so that he can even change the amount of time waited dynamically in order to have some control about how much cpu would be used.

However, my gut tells me that ain't right either. What do you think about introducing Thread.sleep to lower the amount of CPU used for a task? Is this common practice? If not, what would be the right approach?

Answer (score 1):

I would highly consider changing your system architecture to offload these long-running requests to a separate instance instead of running them in-process with the general request-service application. In general I think it is an anti-pattern to handle both batch / online (or long / short running) processing in the same application instance.

Ideally you'd build a standalone microservice to handle these requests, but you could also simply just deploy X instances of your existing application, and configure your load balancer to route requests to the long running invocation paths (e.g. `POST /myapp/longrunningjob`) only to the instances dedicated to running these long-running processes.